# Import statement of ClassA within ClassA ?? why did designers allow this.?

Tags: java, import

I have below doubt on import statement in java.

```
    package com.punith.test;
    import **com.punith.test.ClassA**;

    public class ClassA {

    }
```

So as in above code i am allowed to import the same class which i am defining ClassA. So why did designers allowed to do this, instead of compilation error corrected to be as a warning.

Regards
Punith

Comment: Why do you think it should be a **compiler error**??

Comment: why would i import the same class ?? throw an error and make the code more efficient, instead of junk within it... my guess was "is there any reason"??

Comment: "Junk" doesn't mean it is wrong. It's redundant, thus compiler warning is more appropriate. not compiler error i think

Comment: Even if it does not make sense I see no problem with it. There is nothing the compiler can handle in this case. So there is no error. Even in my eyes this is a case for a lint.

Comment: *throw an error and make the code more efficient* - what kind of efficiency do you talking about? This class was loaded by ClassLoader anyway, what is your problem?

Comment: its redundancy of bytes for the classLoader to read byte[] and construct the class... isn't it ??

Comment: @PermGenError I agree with Punith Raj, because at the point where the class itself is imported, the class itself is not complete. So shouldn't be there some error or atleast some warning?

Comment: @Punith Unused imports have no effect on the classloader.  Imports are not retained during runtime; the classloader loads a class as it is required.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav see my second comment. It's just reduandant code.at most you can expect a compiler warning of some sort not compiler error for this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a special case of an unused import, which quite rightly don't throw compile errors.  There is no performance hit from unused imports since this is a compile-time indicator that you intend to use a class at runtime.

There are countless ways to create pointless code; to have each one throw a compile time error would make the compiler considerably more complex.  Best to rely on an element of common sense from the developer and when common sense fails (all too often), optimise out the dodgy code - which happens in this case.

Comment: i agree to your "Pointless code" phrase because i am allowed to import the same statement infinite times and compiler still smiles at me :)

Answer (score 0):

Importing class it self doesn't gives compilation errors, but there is no point to putting that as a import to it self.

Comment: Please mention this is in comment. This is not an answer nor explanantion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some thoughts about your question.

First of all, lets consider, why compiler deprecates some code constructions? In which case? Obviously, any compiler error is the signal about incomprehensible part of code, which can not be correctly translated into low-level instructions, and so it can not be interpreted by JVM. All other cases, which are senseless or absurd, but which could be implemented - aren't deprecated. For example, you can also do a lot of meaningless things in Java:

```
public void nop() {
    int i;
}
```

or

```
for (int x = 0; x < 0; x++);
```

or

```
int i = 1;
i = i;
```

Secondly thought about `import` statement is not exactly about your question, but it is close by it. There is also `import static` statement. This is a very case where static import of same class, which is described in this file is sensible thing. For example it is helpful in such situation:

```
package xxx;
import static xxx.TestEnum.Test.*;
public class TestEnum {
    enum Test {
        TEST1,
        TEST2
    }
    public boolean isTest2(Test test) {
        return test == TEST2;
    }
}
```

In this code without `import static xxx.TestEnum.Test.*` we can not use such construction as `test == TEST2;`. Without such import it will be `compile error` and we have to change it to `return test == Test.TEST2;`.

Comment: it would have been a better design to language if we were not allowed to do those meaningless things... anyways i at least expected warning when i copied same import statement 10 times.. :) . and compiler had nothing to complain for

Comment: @PunithRaj this is because compiler is very clever: he will eliminate this imports in produced binary code.